# Invalid refresh token

Tags: php, api

devs.

I'm having trouble uploading videos to Dailymotion. The first upload works, when I tried to send a second video I get an error mesage, and so on, one video is sent and the other one fails. The error message is:

"Invalid refresh token"

My code

```
$url = $request->file("file");
$api = new Dailymotion();
$api->setGrantType(
Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD,
"xxxxxxxxx",
"xxxxxxxx",
array("manage_videos","userinfo","manage_playlists","manage_user_settings","manage_applications"),
array(
"username" => "xxx@xxx.com.br",
"password" => "xxx",
));
$api->logout();
$videoUrl = $api->uploadFile($url);

$result = $api->post(
"/me/videos",
array("url" => $videoUrl, "title" =>"teste de vídeo"
));
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with their API, but it doesn't seem like you should be calling `logout()` before you upload the file and post it.

Comment: If I change the place logout, it does not upload the video, I get a similar error. Unauthorized application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
$url = $request->file("file");
$api = new Dailymotion();
$api->setGrantType(Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD,"xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx",array("manage_videos","userinfo","manage_playlists","manage_user_settings","manage_applications"),
array("username" => "xxx@xxx.com.br","password" => "xxx",));
$videoUrl = $api->uploadFile($url);

$result = $api->post(
"/me/videos",
array("url" => $videoUrl, "title" =>"teste de vídeo"
));

$api->logout();
```